# Prestashop 1.7 renderform by admincontroller error

Tags: forms, module, controller, prestashop, helper

for my module i need to generate a form with helper. I found nothing with my error on the web so... I post again something...

Here my AdminYoutubeHomeController

```
<?php


class AdminYoutubeHomeController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->display = 'view';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->meta_title = $this->l('Youtube');
        if (!$this->module->active) {
            Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminHome'));
        }
    }

    public function renderView()
    {
        /**
         * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
         */
        if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitYoutubeHomeModule')) == true) {
            $this->postProcess();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'youtube_dir', _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'youtubehome',
            'youtube_embeded' => "https://www.youtube.com/embed/",
            'youtubeLink' => Configuration::get('YOUTUBEHOME_LINK_VIDEO')

        ]);

        return $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'youtubehome/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl').$this->renderForm();
    }

    /**
     * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
     */
    public function renderForm()
    {
        $helper = new HelperForm();

        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->name_controller = $this->module->name;
        $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitYoutubeHomeModule';

        $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
            .'&configure='.$this->module->name.'&tab_module='.$this->module->tab.'&module_name='.$this->module->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

        $helper->tpl_vars = array(
            'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
            'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
        );

        return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
    }

    /**
     * Create the structure of your form.
     */
    public function getConfigForm()
    {
        return array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'col' => 3,
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'prefix' => '<i class="icon icon-youtube-play"></i>',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Enter your youtube end link'),
                        'name' => 'YOUTUBEHOME_LINK_VIDEO',
                        'label' => $this->l('Link'),
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set values for the inputs.
     */
    public function getConfigFormValues()
    {
        return array(
            'YOUTUBEHOME_LINK_VIDEO' => Configuration::get('YOUTUBEHOME_LINK_VIDEO'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Save form data.
     */
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

        foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
            Configuration::updateValue($key, Tools::getValue($key));
        }
    }

}
```

And here the error

[image]

My tpl file is in modules/youtubehome/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl

I don't want to override the default form. Do you think i have doing something wrong ?

*EDIT POST*

Here it's the error with ps_version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
$this->setTemplate('module:youtubehome/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl');
```

Regards

Comment: thanks for you answer, i have try. I have an other error. The controller try to found the template in themes/default/template/module:youtubehome/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl' and found nothing. 

It's normal, my template is in modules/youtubehome/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl

Comment: and try with : $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl');

Comment: Thanks. I have try and i have 

"Warning: Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Same with _FILE_ i have try with _PS_MODULE_DIR_ and the error is 

"Notice: Undefined index: ps_version"

Comment: Try with :  $this->display(dirname(__FILE__), '/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl');

Comment: Thanks, same error : "Warning: Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: yes, error syntax, try : $this->display(dirname( _ _ FILE _ _ ), '/views/templates/admin/youtubehome.tpl'); (we must remove the spaces between the _)

Comment: Always the same error :/ Thanks to trying to help me

Comment: you put no space between (and _), because when I stick two _ without removing them on the message

Comment: Ok i think it's good but now i have : "Notice: Undefined index: ps_version" and in the symfony error log i can see : "User Deprecated: AdminMarketing is a deprecated tab since version 1.7.0 and "Default" will be removed in 1.7.1.. Upgrade module using the docs: http://build.prestashop.com/news/how-we-reorganized-main-menu-prestashop-1.7/."

Comment: For the record it does not matter. For the ps version variable tried with _ PS_VERSION _ you put no space between (and _)

Comment: i only have _PS_VERSION_ in my youtubehome.php in the constructor

"$this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' =>_PS_VERSION_);"

So i don't know why this error happening... In which file is doing wrong

Comment: You can delete this line in your module, it is not used for much

Comment: Thanks, but it's always the same problem.. I have edit my post to give you my error with ps_version...

Comment: try Clear cache. PS_VERSION whats is error ? screenshot ?

Comment: after clear cache nothing better, and yes it's the screenshot